# Spark Schedule: FIFO or FAIR?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

How to choose Spark Scheduler: FIFO or FAIR?

What is the different between Spark Scheduler and YARN Scheduler?

Answer (score 5):

When you submit your jobs in the cluster either with spark-submit or any other mean, it will be given to [Spark schedulers](https://trongkhoanguyenblog.wordpress.com/2015/03/28/understand-the-scheduler-component-in-spark-core/) which is responsible to materialize logical plan of your jobs. In spark, we have `two` modes.

### 1. FIFO

---

By default, Spark’s scheduler runs jobs in FIFO fashion. Each job is divided into `stages` (e.g. map and reduce phases), and the `first` job gets priority on all available resources while its stages have tasks to launch, then the `second` job gets priority, etc. If the jobs at the head of the queue don’t need to use the whole cluster, later jobs can start to run right away, but if the jobs at the head of the queue are large, then later jobs may be delayed significantly.

---

### 2. FAIR

---

The fair scheduler also supports grouping jobs into pools and setting different scheduling options (e.g. weight) for each pool. This can be useful to create a `high-priority` pool for more important jobs, for example, or to group the jobs of each user together and give users equal shares regardless of how many concurrent jobs they have instead of giving jobs equal shares. This approach is modeled after the *Hadoop* Fair Scheduler.

Without any intervention, newly submitted jobs go into a default pool, but jobs’ pools can be set by adding the `spark.scheduler.pool` "local property" to the SparkContext in the thread that’s submitting them.

---

[For more info](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/job-scheduling.html)

Comment: this is just a straight copy and paste from the spark docs